# zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file Error

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to use the following code to match students to their preferred courses.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, preferences, english, mathematics, science):
        self.name = name
        self.preferences = preferences
        self.english = english
        self.mathematics = mathematics
        self.science = science
        self.assigned_course = None

class Course:
    def __init__(self, name, capacity, criteria):
        self.name = name
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.enrolled_students = []
        self.criteria = criteria

def read_students_from_excel(file_path):
    students_df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Students')
    students = []

    for index, row in students_df.iterrows():
        name = row['Name']
        preferences = row['Preferences']
        english = row['English']
        mathematics = row['Mathematics']
        science = row['Science']
        student = Student(name, preferences, english, mathematics, science)
        students.append(student)

    return students

def read_courses_from_excel(file_path):
    courses_df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Courses')
    courses = []

    for index, row in courses_df.iterrows():
        name = row['Name']
        capacity = row['Capacity']
        criteria = row['Criteria']

        # Define criteria functions based on the "Criteria" column
        def course_criteria(student):
            return eval(criteria)  # Evaluate the criteria expression

        course = Course(name, capacity, course_criteria)
        courses.append(course)

    return courses

def match_students_to_courses(students, courses):
    for student in students:
        for preference in student.preferences:
            for course in courses:
                if (
                    course.name == preference
                    and len(course.enrolled_students) < course.capacity
                    and course.criteria(student)
                ):
                    course.enrolled_students.append(student)
                    student.assigned_course = course.name
                    break

def write_results_to_excel(students, file_path):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = load_workbook(file_path)

    students_df = pd.DataFrame([(student.name, student.assigned_course) for student in students], columns=['Name', 'Assigned Course'])
    students_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Results', index=False)

    writer.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_excel_file = "input_data.xlsx"
    output_excel_file = "output_data.xlsx"

    students = read_students_from_excel(input_excel_file)
    courses = read_courses_from_excel(input_excel_file)

    match_students_to_courses(students, courses)
    write_results_to_excel(students, output_excel_file)`
```

However, I encountered the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\subjectallocation.py", line 84, in <module>
    write_results_to_excel(students, output_excel_file)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\subjectallocation.py", line 69, in write_results_to_excel
    writer.book = load_workbook(file_path)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 344, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 123, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 95, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\zipfile\__init__.py", line 1338, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\zipfile\__init__.py", line 1405, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: No. In fact when I tried one of the solutions to install openpyxl==2.6.3, I got another error:   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations. Did you mean: 'cfloat'?

Comment: That almost certainly means the file isn't a valid Excel file. `xlsx' is a ZIP package containing XML files. Many lazy developers fake Excel support though, by creating either a CSV or HTML file with a fake `.xls` or `.xlsx` connection. When you double click on such a file Excel sees it's not a real Excel file and imports it as CSV or HTML.

Comment: But the excel file I created is opened successfully using Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Does `output_data.xlsx` exist in the first place? Is it an existing file? Where did it come from?

Comment: output_data.xlsx is an excel file that is the output file i.e. the code is supposed to produce it.

Comment: Without access to that file, all we can tell you is what's already in the error message.

Comment: This is the link to the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bwEvNSpHsUgH3U-wWC_h7k53k0U4XAX2/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101461883529234348989&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the `write_results_to_excel` function, you can modify it as follows

```
def write_results_to_excel(students, file_path):
    students_df = pd.DataFrame([(student.name, student.assigned_course) for student in students], columns=['Name', 'Assigned Course'])
    with  pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode="a") as writer:
        students_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Results', index=False)

        writer.save()
```

Comment: It would be useful to describe what the error is/was and why your version is different

Comment: Thanks. However, now I get the following error:   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations. Did you mean: 'cfloat'?